# two DropDownPicker, one is depnedent on another one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

**I have two DropDownPicker, one is dependent on another one. If I'm selecting color in one drop down, different colors like yellow, red etc should display on another dropdown but  second dropdown is blank and not showing any color. Does any one has any idea how to work with two dependent dropedownpicker.
PLease help me out here. Here is the snack link
https://snack.expo.dev/r-s8KHKyO
Below is my code:**

```
const CarList = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
        const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
        const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
        const [childOpen, setChildOpen] = useState(false);
        const [filterOption, setfilteroption] = useState([     
            {label: 'Model', value: 'model'},
            {label: 'Year', value: 'year'},
            {label: 'Color', value: 'color'},
          ]);
          const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
          const [childItem, setChilditem] = useState(null);
          const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState([]); 
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setIsLoading(true);  
            fetch(`https://myfakeapi.com/api/cars/?seed=1&page=1&results=20`)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(response => {
                setData(response.cars);
                setFullData(response.cars);
                setIsLoading(false);
              })
          }, []);
          
    const changeSelectOptionHandler = (item) => {
      const colorData = [...new Set(data.map((val) => val.car_color))];
      var color = colorData.map(function (val, index) {
        return {
            id: index,
            value: val
           
        }
    })
    
      
       setSelected(item.label);
       if (selected === "Color") {
        console.log("hi", item.value)
        setChildValue(color)
    //console is showing it undefined (console.log(setChildValue(color))
     }
     };
      
         
          function renderHeader() {
            return (   
              <View>
                <TextInput
                  //some code
                />
                
              <View>
                <DropDownPicker onSelectItem={changeSelectOptionHandler}
         open={open} 
         value={value}
         items={filterOption}
         setOpen={setOpen}
         setValue={setValue}
         setItems={setfilteroption}
         dropDownDirection="TOP"
         key={filterOption}
 
        /> 
                   
       </View>
                <View>
                   <DropDownPicker
           open={childOpen}
            items={childValue}
        value = {childItem}
      setValue = {setChilditem}
            setOpen={setChildOpen}
            setItems={setChildValue.value}
            max={10}
            dropDownDirection="TOP"
            testID="picker-testid"
            key={setChildValue.id}
 
          /> 
             </View>
              </View>
              
            );
          }  
      
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
         //FlatList
        </View>   
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: can you please share code in snack so I can implement that.

Comment: Here is the Link https://snack.expo.dev/r-s8KHKyO

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues that were causing the second dropdown to not be filled with filtered data.

I refactored the code as below :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import filter from "lodash.filter";
import DropDownPicker from "react-native-dropdown-picker";

const CarList = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [fullData, setFullData] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [childOpen, setChildOpen] = useState(false);

  const [filterOption, setfilteroption] = useState([
    { label: "Model", value: "model" },
    { label: "Year", value: "year" },
    { label: "Color", value: "color" },
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [childItem, setChilditem] = useState(null);
  const [childValue, setChildValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://myfakeapi.com/api/cars/?seed=1&page=1&results=20`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.cars);
        setFullData(response.cars);

        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#5500dc" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>
          Error fetching data... Check your network connection!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const handleSearch = (text) => {
    const formattedQuery = text.toLowerCase();
    const filteredData = filter(fullData, (user) => {
      return contains(user, formattedQuery);
    });
    setData(filteredData);
    setQuery(text);
  };

  const contains = ({ car, car_model, car_color }, query) => {
    if (
      car.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
      car_model.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||
      car_color.toLowerCase().includes(query)
    ) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

  const changeSelectOptionHandler = (item) => {
    const colorData = [...new Set(data.map((val) => val.car_color))];
    const modelData = [...new Set(data.map((val) => val.car_model))];
    const yearData = [...new Set(data.map((val) => val.car_model_year))];
    var color = colorData.map(function (val, index) {
      return {
        id: index,
        value: val,
        label: val,
      };
    });

    var model = modelData.map(function (val, index) {
      return {
        id: index,
        value: val,
        label: val,
      };
    });

    var year = yearData.map(function (val, index) {
      return {
        id: index,
        value: val,
        label: val,
      };
    });

    setSelected(item.label);
    if (selected === "Color") {
      setChildValue(color);
    } else if (selected === "Model") {
      setChildValue(model);
    } else if (selected === "Year") {
      setChildValue(year);
    }
  };

  function renderHeader() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          padding: 10,
          marginVertical: 10,
          borderRadius: 20,
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          clearButtonMode="always"
          value={query}
          onChangeText={(queryText) => handleSearch(queryText)}
          placeholder="Search"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff", paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        />

        <View>
          <DropDownPicker
            onSelectItem={changeSelectOptionHandler}
            open={open}
            value={value}
            items={filterOption}
            setOpen={setOpen}
            setValue={setValue}
            setItems={setfilteroption}
            dropDownDirection="TOP"
            key={filterOption}
            zIndex={1000}
            zIndexInverse={3000}
            testID="picker-testid"
            style={{
              padding: 5,
              margin: 5,
              width: 200,
              flexDirection: "row",
             
              // borderRadius: 20
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <DropDownPicker
            open={childOpen}
            items={childValue}
            value={childItem}
            setValue={setChilditem}
            setOpen={setChildOpen}
            setItems={childValue}
            max={10}
            dropDownDirection="TOP"
          
            testID="picker-testid"
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              margin: 10,
              width: 200,
              flexDirection: "row",

              // borderRadius: 20
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Favorite Contacts</Text>
      <FlatList
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({ id }) => id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: "https://picsum.photos/200",
              }}
              style={styles.coverImage}
            />
            <View style={styles.metaInfo}>
              <Text
                style={styles.title}
              >{`${item.car} ${item.car_model}`}</Text>
              <Text>Color: {`${item.car_color}`}</Text>
              <Text>Price: {`${item.price}`}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#101010",
    marginTop: 60,
    fontWeight: "700",
  },
  listItem: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  coverImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  metaInfo: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    width: 200,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default CarList;
```

You can also check the working demo here - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/4a3bc4

Comment: Check new solution with demo